# In derby should I be using the APP schema or the MYDBNAME schema

Tags: database, derby, javadb

Every time I create a derby database there are several schemas including the APP schema and a schema with the same name of the USERNAME. Which schema should i be using, the APP or the USERNAME schema? Why is the APP schema introduced if the USERNAME schema is set as the default schema. Hopefully this is a quick question for a derby pro. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any schema you want. If you don't explicitly specify a schema, Derby picks a default schema for you. http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqlj32268.html. I'm not sure why you are getting a schema with the same name as your database; are you setting that schema intentionally?

Comment: hi brian actually i was mistaken it was the name of the username supplied when i created the db in netbean Services tab. It appears the username schema is also being set as the default schema which i'm not sure if it should be this way...

Comment: Yes, your username establishes a default schema if you do not explicitly use the SET SCHEMA statement.