# Spring JDBCTemplate Specify Schema for Derby

Tags: java, schema, derby, spring-jdbc

While setting up a derby connection if we use plain java code we can specify the schema for given connection using

```
conn.setSchema("APP");
```

When we using `JDBCTemplate` we have to specify `DataSource` object to this template. There is no `setSchema` method in DataSource class.

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource=new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
dataSource.setUrl(url);
dataSource.setUsername(username);
dataSource.setPassword(password);
```

Also i could not specify it as derby properties. Derby properties mentioned in the DOCs.

```
bootPassword=key 
create=true 
databaseName=nameofDatabase    
dataEncryption=true 
encryptionProvider=providerName    
encryptionAlgorithm=algorithm 
territory=ll_CC    
logDevice=logDirectoryPath 
createFrom=BackupPath    
restoreFrom=BackupPath 
rollForwardrecoveryFrom=BackupPath    
password=userPassword 
shutdown=true 
user=userName
```

What is the best way to overcome this issue. Is there any solution to specify schema?

Comment: To clarify: you are trying to get Spring to use a explicit schema name, not the default schema name (which is derived from the name of the user)?

Comment: Yes. Will it use username or APP as default

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040213/in-derby-should-i-be-using-the-app-schema-or-the-mydbname-schema and also see this page in particular from the Derby docs about how it picks the default schema name: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefsqlj32268.html